# Nested aggregate function in SELECT list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I tried following query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(SUM(e.Empid))
FROM HR.Employees
```

and got following error:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

My question is why isn't this allowed?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: It is not allowed, because it is kinda useless?

Comment: This is simple query, approximated from one big query, and I unintentional try this form and got error, and I change my query to get result. But, later i thought about this construction and have not idea why this will be error. It doesn't matter what I want to return, but why this raise an error

Comment: Refer my ans  @veljasije

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate but I can do so by creating a new select statement around it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747963/why-cant-i-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-expression-containing-an-aggrega)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have not define any columns to be grouped, The value of `SUM()` is equal to `MAX()`

**UPDATE**

An error was thrown because `MAX(SUM(e.Empid))` requires the results of two grouped selects, not just one.

Comment: Even if I add group by clause, I still getting error? My question is why is this error instead some inappropriate value or something else?

Comment: @veljasije because `max(sum(value))` requires the results of two grouped selects, not just one.

Comment: If I understand well, first I need execute one aggregate function, which result another grouped result set, and then I need to evaluate second aggregate function. In other words, SELECT list was processing complete like one phase, and in that step can make only one aggregation?

Comment: @veljasije yes, that's right. but i hope `MAX(SUM(e.Empid))` is only an example, not that you want to get the `MAX` value of the result of `SUM` because it makes no sense. hehe

Comment: Exactly, this is only an example, I have more focused on processing query, because I wrote simple example. Write you comment as answer, please.

Comment: @veljasije which one? i added the first one.

Answer (score 6):

Each aggregate works on a group.  You can only define one group per query.  So multiple aggregates require subqueries.  For example, to find the amount of employees in the largest department:

```
SELECT  MAX(EmpCount)
FROM    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) as EmpCount
        FROM    HR.Employees
        GROUP BY
                e.Department
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM(x)` evaluates to a single value, so it's not appropriate to `MAX` the result of it.

Answer (score 0):

This query makes no sense, as even if it worked, it would return only one value : the sum of Empid. The `MAX` function applied on one value is not really useful.

Comment: I know that this query makes no sense, but i need to know why isn't allowed internally?

Comment: Maybe this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747963/why-cant-i-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-expression-containing-an-aggrega

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(_ID)
FROM (SELECT SUM(e.Empid) _ID FROM HR.Employees e) t
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got your question now. Here is why:

> The value expression simply contained in set function specification
>   shall not contain a set function specification or a subquery. If the
>   value expression contains a column reference that is an outer
>   reference, then that outer reference shall be the only column
>   reference contained in the value expression.

Further reading : SQL 92 Standards

Raj