# compute the `SUM(Count(id))`

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

To compute the `SUM(Count(id))` i used this query.I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747963/why-cant-i-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-expression-containing-an-aggrega)

```
Select  *,SUM(Solders) as sums

From
(SELECT   
       Groups.[ID] 
      , Groups.[Name] 
      ,Count( Solders.ID)   as Solders

  FROM  Groups join Solders on Groups.ID=Solders.GID 


       group by   Groups.[ID],Groups.[Name]
   )B
```

but this error happen:

```
Column 'B.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory.  Once you introduce an aggregate function in your query, you have to either aggregate  or group by every column in the query.    Since you're summing `Solders`, you'll need to group by ID and Name in your outer query.

Comment: That is because you have `*` in the top SELECT.  Remove the `*`, or add `group by` on ID/Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions instead:

```
SELECT g.[ID], g.[Name], Count(s.ID) as Solders,
       SUM(Count(s.Id)) OVER () as SumCount
FROM Groups g join
     Solders s
     on g.ID = s.GID 
GROUP BY g.[ID], g.[Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard group by it looks like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME,SUM(Solders) as sums
FROM
  (SELECT   
     Groups.[ID] 
     , Groups.[Name] 
     ,Count( Solders.ID)   as Solders
   FROM  Groups join Solders on Groups.ID=Solders.GID 
   GROUP BY Groups.[ID],Groups.[Name]
  )B
GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

Comment: Is this not redundant?  The `SUM()` can't aggregate the data further than the `COUNT()` if it has the same `group by`.

Comment: @JiggsJedi - I've no idea -- I assume this is a simplified version of the original problem and this answer will point in the right way.