# How can i use count and take the average of it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, average, sql-server-2014

Instead of long explaining the question i'm just going to show what i've tried, Btw, i am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) and working on Northwind;

```
select FirstName+' '+LastName Employee, count(ShipName) OrderQuantity, 
    case
        when count(ShipName)<50 then 'You're Fired!!!'
            when count(ShipName) between 50 and avg(count(ShipName))/count(FirstName) then 'Be Careful!'
    else 'You're the CEO Next Year'
    end Yorum
from Orders left join Employees
            on Employees.EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID
group by FirstName+' '+LastName
order by OrderQuantity
```

When i execute this query i get the following error;

```
"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."
```

I'm trying to get the average of the OrderQuantity column which i grouped, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is that:

- group by FirstName+' '+LastName

You should try run first a subquery doing this union First + Last Name to it be a field, it is impossible to sql server determine FirstName+' '+LastName as a field. Try to run the group by with only one of these field or

- group by FirstName,LastName (just to see if this is the problem)

Well, maybe:

```
SELECT    fullname        employee , 
          Count(shipname) orderquantity , 
          CASE 
                    WHEN Count(shipname)<50 THEN 'You're fired!!!' when count(ShipName) between 50 and avg(count(ShipName))/count(EmployeeID) then 'be careful!' else 'you're the CEO Next Year' 
          END yorum 
FROM      orders 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                 SELECT (firstname+' '+lastname) 'FullName', 
                        firstname, 
                        lastname, 
                        employeeid 
                 FROM   employees )tb1 
ON        tb1.employeeid == orders.employeeid 
GROUP BY  tb1.fullname 
ORDER BY  count(shipname) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Vitor Luiz da Silva but i get the same error again with this solution.

Comment: Try to begin with only one field and remove the AVG expression to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(ShipName)` returns only one row for that group and there is no point in averaging that.

`AVG(COUNT(ShipName)) == COUNT(ShipName)`

Remove Avg() and it should work. You can use avg() on resultset

check the below link it might be useful

[Why can't I perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate but I can do so by creating a new select statement around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747963/why-cant-i-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-expression-containing-an-aggrega)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use `AVG` with the `OVER` clause:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    select 
        FirstName+' '+LastName AS Employee
        ,count(ShipName) AS OrderQuantity
    from 
        Orders 
        left join Employees on Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
    group by FirstName+' '+LastName
)
SELECT
    Employee
    ,OrderQuantity
    ,case
        when OrderQuantity < 50 then 'You are Fired!!!'
        when OrderQuantity between 50 and AVG(OrderQuantity) OVER() then 'Be Careful!'
        else 'You are the CEO Next Year'
    end AS Yorum
FROM CTE
order by OrderQuantity;
```

At first calculate `COUNT` for each employee in the CTE. Then you can compare the `OrderQuantity` with the global average of Order counts for all employees using `AVG() OVER()`.